# How to update only clicked element using useState?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state, use-state

I have a list of chapters that have a list of steps. I am trying to add a step to a chapter when clicking the button, but I am currently adding a step to all of the chapters instead.
What am I doing wrong?

```
  const dummy_chapters = [
    { id: 1, title: 'Chapter 1'},
    { id: 2, title: 'Chapter 2'},
    { id: 2, title: 'Chapter 3'},
  ]

const dummy_steps = [
    { id: 1, title: 'Step 1'},
    { id: 2, title: 'Step 2'},
  ]

  const [chapters, setChapters] = React.useState(dummy_chapters)
  const [steps, setSteps] = React.useState(dummy_steps)

  const addStep = () => {
    setSteps([
      ...steps,
      {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Another step'
      },
    ])
  }

  return (
      <List>
          {chapters.map((d, idx) => (
              <ChapterListItem    
                  secondaryAction={
                    <IconButton onClick={addStep}>
                      <MoreVertIcon/>
                    </IconButton>
                  }>
                  </ChapterListItem>
                <List component='div' disablePadding>
                  {steps?.map((d, idx) => (
                    <ListItemText primary={d.title}/>
                  ))} 
                </List> 
          ))}
      </List>
          <Icon onClick={addChapter} iconId='add' />
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: addChapter is not defined in your example

Comment: It's not in this example, but it's basically the same as addStep.

Comment: There is no relation between chapters and steps in your current question. How are you going to set relation between steps and chapters?

Comment: @SanketShah Indeed, it’s part of my problem and I’m trying to find the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of managing `chapters` and `steps` differently you can add `steps` key inside of each `chapters`. Then for adding new steps you can try approach as mentioned below.

```
    const dummy_chapters = [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'Chapter 1',
        steps: [{
            id: 1,
            title: 'Step 1'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Step 2'
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Chapter 2',
        steps: []
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Chapter 3',
        steps: []
      },
    ]

    const dummy_steps = [
        { id: 1, title: 'Another Chapter'},
      ]

     const [chapters, setChapters] = React.useState(dummy_chapters)

      const addStep = (chapterId) => {
        const updatedChapters = chapters?.map((chapter) => {
          if(chapter?.id === chapterId){
            chapter[steps] = [...chapter.steps, ...dummy_steps]
          }
          return chapter
        })
        setChapters(updatedChapters)
      }

      return (
          <List>
              {chapters.map((chapter, idx) => (
                  <ChapterListItem    
                      secondaryAction={
                        <IconButton onClick={() =>addStep(chapter?.id)}>
                          <MoreVertIcon/>
                        </IconButton>
                      }>
                      </ChapterListItem>
                    <List component='div' disablePadding>
                      {chapter?.steps?.map((step, idx) => (
                        <ListItemText primary={step.title}/>
                      ))} 
                    </List> 
              ))}
          </List>
              <Icon onClick={addChapter} iconId='add' />
          </Box>
        </>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a field (like `chapterId: 1` in your steps object, and then before incrementing add a condition to check chapter id before increment.
That way you can increment steps for the chapter you want.

Comment: Basically you just need to create some sort of relation between objects, right now they are independent but you need to make the step object dependent on the chapter object.